# Absolute value calculation

Tags: c, floating-point, integer

When calculating the absolute value of an integer or a floating point value, is there any advantage of using *abs* from stdlib.h or *fabs* from math.h compared to using the conditional operator?

```
#define ABS(x) (((x) >= 0)? (x): -(x))
```

Comment: Try `abs(x++)`, see where the macro takes you.

Comment: Yes, the `abs` and `fabs`  functions are *standard* functions. And they are *functions*, not macros.

Comment: The code might be more readable if `abs` or `fabs` is used.

Comment: Furthermore, the `abs` and the `fabs` functions do different things. Calling `abs` with a floating point value will most likely not do what you want it to do.

Comment: @EOF If *abs* from stdlib.h is implemented as a real function (rather than a macro) I'm thinking that the function call overhead would be significant in relation to what the function does.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom A decent optimizing compiler will happily inline the functions for you. The performance benefit of using a macro is negligible to zero, or even negative.

Comment: I think (it is only an opinion) that macros are faster, because there is not a function call (jump, memory heap, return,...).

Comment: @Alexi [Stuff can get inlined though](https://godbolt.org/g/Z3VRHY) (note no `call abs`).

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: DId you check the assembler code? DId you benchmark? Define "advantage". Don't try to outsmart the compiler. gcc for instance is aware of most standard functions and can emit optimised code. Your question shows not a bit of own research effort!

Comment: @EOF: In case of `abs(x++)` it won't give expected output but surely is problematic because it will increment X. right ?

Comment: @Destructor: Any side effect caused by a function argument will happen exactly *once*, because the argument is *evaluated* once. A macro may refer to its argument multiple times (or zero times), thus causing side effects associated with the evaluation of the argument to be triggered multiple times, or not at all.

Comment: @Siguza you are right, there is not function calls. In fact, both "abs" and "ABS" generate exactly the same assembly code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code should use `abs()` with `int` (or narrower), `fabs()` with double, `fabsf()` with `float`, `labs(x)` with `long`, etc. [@Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099198/absolute-value-calculation/39100376#comment65545104_39099198)

1. Advantage: non-macro.  Macro `ABS()` evaluates the argument twice, likely not desired as in `ABS(x++)`. [@EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099198/absolute-value-calculation#comment65544991_39099198) and [@EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099198/absolute-value-calculation#comment65546774_39099198)
2. Advantage: non-macro.  Sequence point definitiveness. [@EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099198/absolute-value-calculation/39100376#comment65547464_39100376)
3. Advantage: non-macro.  `-0.0` returns `-0.0` with OP's `ABS()`.  `fabs(-0.0)` returns `0.0`.  if following IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic.
4. Advantage: non-macro.  `ABS(0.0/0.0)` attempts to change the sign. (Corner case concern).
5. Advantage: non-macro.  `abs()`, `fabs()` are standard functions, readily understood by reviewers.  `ABS()` is not.
6. Performance: Profile to find what is best on your platform.  What is *best* (speed, code size, memory size) varies by compiler.
7. No type checking with `ABS()`.
8. Cannot take the address of the macro.

Comment: 7. Function call is sequence-point. `x = abs(x++)` well-defined, `x = ABS(x++)` undefined. I'm not sure point 3 is particularly important though, the signedness of `NAN` is implementation-defined IIRC.

Comment: @EOF Agree #3 is not generally important, hence the "Corner case concern".